# How do you use a loop to get the least significant digit of a number?

Tags: python, loops

I am a little confused with what the question is asking me to do here —-> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSfHH.jpg)

This is using python and the rules are: 
Only loops and conditionals can be used

Comment: The modulus is increasing to get the individual digits of the number. Now do this in a loop by multiplying the modulus.

Comment: Multiplying the modulus?

Comment: What do you mean by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions to your problem. First one is using recursion and the second one is counter.

```
def contains_two_fives_loop(n):
    """Using loop."""
    counter = 0
    while n:
        counter += n % 10 == 5
        n //= 10
    return 2 <= counter


def contains_two_fives_recursion(n):
    """Using recursion."""
    return 2 <= (n % 10) == 5 + contains_two_fives(n // 10)


def contains_two_fives_str_counter(n):
    """Convert to string and count 5s in the string."""
    return 2 <= str(n).count("5")
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I thought we had to use a for loop, no wonder I was lost

Comment: There are two types of loops in Python - 'for' and 'while'. Other languages (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript ...) also have 'do-while' loop.